# gallery switcher( c# visual)

Tags: c#, gallery

Why does this not work?

There are two Radio buttons.

If I check radio button1 I should see gallery1. 
If I check Radio button2 I should see galery2.

And button1"`<<`"  button2 "`>>`" is meant to view  gallery : back, forward.

http://s1v3.irc.lv/files/1/0/0/454/KddPouO7.png

http://s1v2.irc.lv/files/1/0/0/454/aHPiAt4k.png

```
    namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            List<string> galerija1;
            List<string> galerija2;
            List<string> aktualaGalerija;
            int tekosaPozicija;

            string galerija1 = new List<string>(){ "C:\\Galerija1\\aq1.png", "C:Galerija1\\aq2.png"};
            string galerija2 = new List<string>(){ "C:Galerija2\\dr1.png", "C:Galerija2\\dr1.png"};**
    /////   He don`t like this place :( Someone can help?

         public Form1()
         {
            InitializeComponent();
         }

        private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          aktualaGalerija = galerija1;
          tekosaPozicija = 0;
          IeladeAktualoBildi();
        }

        private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            aktualaGalerija = galerija2;
            tekosaPozicija = 0;
            IeladeAktualoBildi();
        }

        private void IeladeAktualoBildi()
        {
           string aktualaBilde = aktualaGalerija[tekosaPozicija];
        }



        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (tekosaPozicija == aktualaGalerija.Count - 1)
                return;
            tekosaPozicija++;
            IeladeAktualoBildi();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (tekosaPozicija == 0)
                return;
            tekosaPozicija--;
            IeladeAktualoBildi();
        }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
List<string> galerija1;
string  galerija1 = new List<string>(){ ... };
```

with

```
List<string> galerija1 = new List<string> { ... };
```

The same with `galerija2`. Your code declares two fields with the same name, but different types.

Comment: Athari, Yeah ok, now there is no mistakes, but that all doesn`t work, I don`t see no picture, no galery :(

Comment: Not enough information. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).